# Need search box filter javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, search

**Todo :**

- I need search box filter in javascript for these which search and filter each
- When I type words e.g like `c` then it show me `calvin, cars, cinama`. 

  Here is an example list.

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li><a HREF="#">KINDY</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">BILLY</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">DOB</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">CALVIN</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">ACNE</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">boil</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">cars</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">cinama</a></li>
>   <li><a HREF="#">lamp</a></li>
> </ul>
> ```

Comment: What have you tried, please show some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a google suggest-like input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795843/how-to-implement-a-google-suggest-like-input-field)

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking for, if yes It works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Is</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">What</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">You</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">are</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Looking?</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)===0) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it should be `a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === 0` , the question wants the starting thing, you are trying to find if the element exists. Anyway, a helpful one.

Comment: above working but it shows filter list .i need this search filter box with hide filter  list.e.g when i enter word 'c' then it will show my results.

Comment: @mibrahim can you please explain a bit, what you want exactly. So that I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [match-sorter](https://github.com/kentcdodds/match-sorter). It does a very good job of doing this fuzzy search.

If you are not using a node/es6 env then you can directly include this library in your code using https://unpkg.com/match-sorter@2.3.0/dist/match-sorter.cjs.js. Include this JS into your HTML and have the search logic within a `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**HTML**

```
<ul id="MyList">
  <li><a href="#">KINDY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">BILLY</a></li>    
  <li><a href="#">DOB</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CALVIN</a></li>    
  <li><a href="#">ACNE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">boil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cars?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cinama</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">lamp</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).on('keyup change','#YourSearchBox',function(){
     var SearchString=$(this).val();
     var Names=$('#MyList').find('a');
     $('#MyList').empty();
     var List='';
     $.each(Names,function(i,ListName){
         if(ListName.text.toLowerCase().includes(SearchString.toLowerCase()))
         {
             List+='<li style="display:block"><a href="#">'+ListName.text+'</a></li>'
         }
         else
         {
            List+='<li style="display:none"><a href="#">'+ListName.text+'</a></li>'
         }
     });
     $('#MyList').append(List);
    });
});
```

Comment: still not working properly to filter words i need complete code with hide search list when i enter words then show me results. any way thanks for help.